# Как определить координату от верха страницы в js

Tags: javascript

Мне известно, что есть метод scrollTop();

Однако в интернете примеры когда он используется на бинд скролла:

```
var position;
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        position = $(document).scrollTop();
    });
```

В Chrome бывает, что позиция скрола на странице сохраняется после ее перезагрузки. Как в этом случае мне получить координату? Если я просто выношу пример `position = $(document).scrollTop();` в верх документа то он всегда равен 0 даже если страница загрузилась с того места скрола где я ее перезагружал. Как тогда быть?

Comment: Хм... Проверил тут же на SO в хроме, `$(document).scrollTop();` показывает все верно даже после перезагрузки. Я думаю, у вас в логике проблема. Вы прибиндили вычисление position на "скролл". А при перезагрузке этот код не работает, вы же не скролите. Я думаю, нужно еще на `$( document ).ready()` повесить

Comment: я это и имел введу. вы меня не поняли. Я и говорю что классический пример когда биндят на скрол. А в хроме у меня страница перезагружается на то место где была до перезагрузки, без скрола. И в этом случае неоткуда взять позицию, а обычный position = $(document).scrollTop(); дает 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с этим методом. Если не получиться дайте знать.

```
function scrollMoveXY() { // положения скрола  на странице
        var x = window.pageXOffset || window.scrollX || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) || (document.body && document.body.scrollLeft) || 0;  
        var y = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollY || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || (document.body && document.body.scrollTop) || 0; 
        return {"x": x,"y": y}
    }

var position;
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        position = scrollMoveXY().y;
    });
```

Comment: Супер! Все круто. Спасибо большое за помощь!